How to only blend background of <section> but not the content
My website is made up of several sections.
I'm looking for a way to only blend the background of one of these sections, but not have it affect the section content.


.bg {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  height:80vh;
}

.section {
  background: linear-gradient(
    124deg,
    rgba(89, 73, 219, 1) 0%,
    rgba(215,234,255,1) 100%
   ); 
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.text-white {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="bg">
    <section class="section">
           <div id="content">
               <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
               <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
               <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
               <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
               <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
           </div>
    </section>
</div>



As you can see, the text is clearly affected, I'd love for the text to remain white.
The problem is, if I move the background gradient and blend mode to one of the divs, it stops working. The way I set up my page it needs to happen on the section level, but I cannot figure out how to stop the content from also blending.
I tried isolation, which didn't work.

Please add the relevant CSS so it's clear what you're trying to achieve. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

i added the css and removed the tailwind parts

You could use a pseudo-element to create the desired background.
This way, the mix-blend-mode only applies to the pseudo-element itself.
The important part is the position: relative; on the #content element, which creates a new stacking context and thus puts the content "in front" of the pseudo-element and its background.


.bg {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  height: 80vh;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
}

.section::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    124deg,
    rgba(89, 73, 219, 1) 0%,
    rgba(215,234,255,1) 100%
   );
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#content {
  position: relative; /* create new stacking context */
}

.text-white {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="bg">
    <section class="section">
       <div id="content">
           <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
           <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
           <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
           <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
           <div class="text-white">TEST</div>
       </div>
    </section>
</div>




Great idea, however I neither see the gradient, nor the blend-mode working... Did it work for you?

I see that you've updated your question and changed the code that was originally provided. I have adapted my answer to your question and it should now work as expected. If it still doesn't work, please provide additional information such as which browser you're using and exactly how the background should look with your background color behind it and the background gradient in front with the blend mode.
